# Class^='instructions'...Only selects first element beginning with class should select all

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

What is wrong with this code block?  It will only select the first element containing instructions but does not select them all.  Why?  What am I missing?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery('select').select2();

    // get a list of objects that begin with instructions
    var classList =  jQuery('a[class^="instructions"]').attr('class').split(/\s+/);
    console.log(classList);
    jQuery.each(classList, function (index, item) {
        jQuery('.'+item+'-'+index).click(
            function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                jQuery(this).parent().next().toggle();
            }
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: You cannot guarantee that class starts with particular string when elements have multiple classes.

Comment: btw there is a property for a class list already - no need to custom split.

Comment: Far better to use a data attribute for this sort of thing, where order can be controlled and relied upon.

Comment: How do you know that the elements have not been selected? Have you tried to log the results of `jQuery('a[class^="instructions"]')`? Or you say that the code does not select more than one element because the rest of your code does not work?

Comment: it was the attr getter a s explained by charlietfl

Comment: Thanks for the help though... I did have some other things I wasn't seeing out of seeing red... Actually didn't even need to do what I was trying to since I am traversing the DOM... just had a brain fart mixed with inexperience.  I'm a developer by hobby, not profession.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`attr()` can only return value from one element when used as a getter and will always return from first element in the collection.

You need to map your own array for all elements something like:

```
var classList =  jQuery('a[class^="instructions"]').map(function(){
  return $(this).attr('class');
}).get();
```